# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 workstation?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, intel

I'm looking to configure a Dell workstation with a processor Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 and I find this message in the Dell webpage:

> The Processor v4 you've selected is incompatible with the Ubuntu 12.04
>   Operating System.

Is this really true? Is it also incompatible with the new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Why would you want to use 12.04 anyway?

Comment: I see Version 3 of that processor listed on http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/PROCESSOR/?&page=21 , but not Version 4. Do you know if it is a "Skylake" processor? I know some people have been having graphics issues with Skyplake processors on Ubuntu (at least until the drivers get better)

Comment: @Android Dev, Ubuntu 12.04 is the only option in the Dell webpage, but I plan to install Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @NickWeinberg - It is a Skylake

Comment: @AndroidDev My understanding is that there are some bugs in Linux and Ubuntu around newer Skylake processors, having to do with video display. Some people have problems, others don't. I think booting with the kernel option `nomodeset` helps some people. The good news is that everything I've read indicates it's a known bug that's anticipated to be fixed sometime soon. I'm no expert in this, but I hope this helps.

Comment: @NickWeinberg - it is not a Skylake processor.

Comment: @MamenArgudoFernández - The Intel page says it was released in Jan 2016, and is 14nm... which means it is a Skylake. http://ark.intel.com/products/92981/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v4-25M-Cache-2_20-GHz

Comment: @AndroidDev Then I'm confused, according to Intel the processor in question is not in the skylake list. http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/37572/Skylake?q=skylake#@All

Comment: @MamenArgudoFernández - I stand corrected. Apparently it is Broadwell. Now why Intel would release a Broadwell CPU in 2016 is beyond me. **In any event, David Foerster's answer still stands.**

Comment: I just bought a Dell workstation T5810 equipped with Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4. I got it shipped with Windows 7 because it was impossible to have it with Ubuntu, and immediately tried and successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 with no problem in configuration and graphic. Haven't tried 16.04 but I think you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel ARK's list of Broadwell processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/38530/Broadwell#@Server) includes the E5-2630 v4. Furthermore it doesn't contain a graphics co-processor.

This means that there should be no problem running it on Ubuntu 16.04. If you want to be sure try a Live DVD/USB.